# ng-repeat not working but can get item of $scope.items on th page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I write a web apps use angular.js and require.js.
But **ng-repeat** doesn't work!
Chroem just show comments when using developer tools.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="over-layout">
     <ul class="list">
        <li ng-repeat="item in items" >
            {{item}}
        </li>  
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="page">
    <div class="header">{{title}}</div>
    <div class="page-view" ng-view></div>
    <div id="footer">
      参考:　<a href="http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/simple-svg-example.html" title="Github">jenkov.com</a>
        {{items[0].title}}
   </div>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
    app.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope) {
        // 文章目录


        $scope.index = 0;
        $scope.title = '开始学习SVG';
        $scope.items = [
            {
                'title': '开始学习SVG',
                'hash': 'home'
            },
            {
                'title': 'svg与g标签',
                'hash': 'svg-el-and-g'
            }

        ];



    $scope.MAX = $scope.items.length;

    $('.bt-menu-trigger').toggle(function(){
        $(this).parent().addClass('bt-menu-open');
        $('.over-layout').addClass('active');
    },function(){
        $(this).parent().removeClass('bt-menu-open');
        $('.over-layout').removeClass('active');
    });

    $scope.select = function($e,item){
        $scope.title = $scope.list[item].title;    
    }


});
```

chrome shows:

```
   <div class="over-layout">
        <ul class="list">
            <!-- ngRepeat: item in items -->  
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: where did you bind your controller to your tag? Or are you doing it in the routeConfig?

Comment: the code html which you put does belong the same controller?

Comment: I bind  ng-controller = "HomeCtrl" on the top div

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you have the items object available in your current scope. I don't see where you are including the controller. Try wrapping that whole html block with:

```
<div data-ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
    <!-- your existing content -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try with:**

```
<li data-ng-repeat="item in items" >
        {{item.title}}
        {{item.hash}}
</li>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I do this! But saddly it still doesn't work! In chrome ,it shows below:

Comment: <!--ngRepeat item in items-->

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="over-layout">
     <ul class="list" ng-repeat="item in items">
        <li>
            {{item}}
        </li>  
    </ul>
</div>
```

pls make this change and let me know...I hope this help u..